# Limiting inrush current in N Channel MOSFET power switch

Tags: mosfet, inrush-current

I have a N-MOSFET as power switch like this:

[image]

I want to add a fuse on the power line but I have few capacitors on the across the load and I am worried that the inrush current might blow the fuse off. How can I limit the inrush current here? I saw that for P-channel one can add capacitor across drain and gate. I am not sure if this works for N-ch MOSFET as well.

Comment: where is that fuse in your diagram?

Comment: whats wrong with the pmos version?

Comment: Nothing wrong with pmos but my VDD will be On only if the FET is on. For pmos I need the VDD to be on all the time.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The fuse will be between the VDD line and the voltage source.

Comment: *I am worried that the inrush current might blow the fuse off.* Before actually solving this "problem" how are you sure it actually **is** a problem? Fuses are **slow** (even the fast ones). I would not try to "fix" this problem before I actually have confirmed that it **is** a problem. There are still many unknowns, like what capacitors (and what is their ESR), what is the supply (perhaps it has a limited output current: problem solved), and even: what fuse?? You're like the rookie engineer who sees problems everywhere due to lack of experience.

Comment: +1 @Bimpelrekkie. Also if the load is inductive like a motor you can use a PWM ramp. If you use a slow switching the FET will dissipate thermal power so is important to make sure it doesn't overheat. See transient thermal impedance in datasheet.

Comment: Add an inductor in series with the load and the capacitors

Comment: What is \$V_{IN}\$, what model is the MOSFET, what is \$V_{DD}\$, what is the load?

Answer (score 1):

With Nmos ist basically the same...cap between gate and source but an additional high side Driver with a high resistance on ist output and a diode in paralell to the resisor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUfI1D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: why is the diode needed?

Comment: @AlexG To allow for slow turn-on and fast turn-off, the diode is needed. It's also  because if the power supply is removed, the capacitor may otherwise stay charged and damage the MOSFET gate (and with the gate driver  being referenced to the source, the voltage in the capacitor is higher than the source, plus the MOSFET source pin will go to 0V once the main power supply is removed, so the gate is now at vSupply + vGate, i.e at 48v + 12v in this case, with the source side falling to 0v.

Answer (score 0):

In this case a cap between drain and gate would limit the rate at which Vds decreases (i.e., Vload increases).  If limiting that voltage ramp will address your inrush current issue, that's the easy route.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR A high gate resistor value will increase the time it takes to charge the mosfet gate, and so the time it takes for it to turn on.**

Found this interesting document about this topic [here](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=13416)

> 2.2. Switching Time and Drive Conditions
>
> Bipolar transistors need a large base current to maintain low on-state
> voltage. In contrast, since  power MOSFETs are voltage-controlled
> devices, they can be driven just by charging gate  capacity, and are
> therefore a low in power consumption. Note, however, that power
> MOSFETs have a slightly large input capacitance Ciss. Thus, for high
> speed switching applications, it is necessary to quickly charge the
> input capacitance from a  low-impedance signal source. Low-impedance
> drive is required to reduce turn-on time. However, the use of a high
> gate  voltage results in the much charging of gate-source capacitance,
> resulting in an increase in td  (off). Switching time can be
> controlled via gate resistance. If you want to change the turn-on and
> turn-off switching speeds separately, you can use diodes to change the
> gate resistance values  for turn-on and turn-off.